# Javascript password validation using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

I have a problem with my password validation using regex on javascript. the criteria are :

1. have at least one or more letter(it can be upper case or lower case)
2. have at least one or more number
3. character length minimal 3 and maximal 30

I hope anyone can help me to solve this problem :)

`var ch_pass = /^([0-9]+).([a-zA-Z]+).({3,30})$/;`

Comment: You can easily check #3 by checking the value's `.length`. For #1 and #2, just use two regular expressions to check that the value contains a alpha and numeric character each. For example: `var value = "YOUR INPUT", alpha = /[A-Za-z]/, numeric = /[0-9]/; if (value.length < 3 || value.length > 30 || !alpha.test(value) || !numeric.test(value)) { /* INVALID */ }`. It's a lot easier to read/understand/maintain, in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead like this:

```
var ch_pass = /^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-zA-Z]).{3,30}$/;
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: That is `lazy vs non-lazy` matching

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend trying to do this whole check in a single regular expression because it just over complicates it. Do each condition individually.

1. Has at least one letter:

   ```
   var has_letters = (/[a-zA-Z]/).test(password);
   ```
2. Has at least one number:

   ```
   var has_numbers = (/[0-9]/).test(password);
   ```
3. Has between 3 and 30 characters (inclusive):

   ```
   var has_length = 3 <= password.length && password.length <= 30;
   ```

This can all be wrapped up into a function:

```
function is_password_valid(password) {
    var has_letters = (/[a-zA-Z]/).test(password);
    var has_numbers = (/[0-9]/).test(password);
    var has_length = 3 <= password.length && password.length <= 30;
    return has_letters && has_numbers && has_length;
}
```

Or if you prefer something more dense:

```
function is_password_valid(password) {
    return ((/[a-zA-Z]/).test(password)
        && (/[0-9]/).test(password)
        && password.length >= 3
        && password.length <= 30);
}
```

Comment: Not that it matters, but `regex.test` makes more sense to use, instead of `.match() != null`. And for #3, you left out the "maximum 30" part

Comment: @Ian Thank you, I wasn't aware of `.test()`.

Comment: Sorry, `test` is a method of a regular expression object. You'd use `var alpha = /[a-zA-Z]/;` and then `alpha.test(password)` - it returns a boolean if it matches or not

Comment: @Ian I guess that's what I get for not double checking.

Comment: As a reference to you or anyone else: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test . And I'd read that page, especially the **Description** because of the quirk when using a global search. Your regexes don't do that, so it should be fine, but in case of future use

Comment: By the way, as my comment on the OP suggests, I think this is answer is better/best. I definitely like your latest updates